# Joining data in lists of list

Tags: r, excel, join

I'm importing data from multiple excel files using the readxl package and I made a function in my script so that I only import specific sheets that I need

```
read_excel_sheets <- function(excelDoc) {
     sheets <- readxl::excel_sheets(excelDoc)
     sheets <- sheets[4:6]
     x <- lapply(sheets, function(X) readxl::read_excel(excelDoc, sheet = X))
     return(x)
}
#load files in folder
rawfiles <- list.files()
IMPORT <- lapply(rawfiles, FUN = read_excel_sheets)
```

After loading the files in my folder into my script, IMPORT becomes a list[10] that contains list[3] inside of it, basically lists inside of a list.

Unfortunately, I can't use reduce(full_join) to gather my data into one data table. I've tried working with just one excel file and using unlist() to see if I can get my sheets out of the lists of list but that did not work.

```
Test <- read_excel_sheets("Hop_L_Trial1.xlsx")
Test_Test <- unlist(Test)
```

I've also tried

```
rawfiles <- list.files()
IMPORT <- lapply(rawfiles,
                FUN = read_excel_sheets) 
Test_3 <- rbindlist(IMPORT)
```

and received an error "Column 1 of item 1 is length 2 inconsistent with column 2 which is length 6. Only length-1 columns are recycled." Any suggestions on how to join my data into one data table would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map_df` from `purrr` to get data as a single dataframe.

```
read_excel_sheets <- function(excelDoc) {
  sheets <- readxl::excel_sheets(excelDoc)
  sheets <- sheets[4:6]
  x <- purrr::map_df(sheets, function(X) readxl::read_excel(excelDoc, sheet = X))
  return(x)
}

IMPORT <- purrr::map_df(rawfiles, FUN = read_excel_sheets)
```

---

You can also use `do.call` + `rbind` base R functions.

```
read_excel_sheets <- function(excelDoc) {
  sheets <- readxl::excel_sheets(excelDoc)
  sheets <- sheets[4:6]
  x <- do.call(rbind, lapply(sheets, function(X) readxl::read_excel(excelDoc, sheet = X)))
  return(x)
}

IMPORT <- do.call(rbind, lapply(rawfiles, FUN = read_excel_sheets))
```

Comment: I used the do.call + rbind method however, I had to use a rbind.fill because sheet 4 has 5 columns, and sheet 5&6 has 9 columns. Now my IMPORT has NA's where the sheets dont match column names. Also, because sheet 5/6 have same variable column names I need someway differentiate which came from sheet 5 and which came from sheet 6.

Comment: @mpvalenc If you use `map_df` you can add an "id" column to know which sheet comes from where. Something like `x <- purrr::map_df(sheets, function(X) readxl::read_excel(excelDoc, sheet = X), .id = "id")`

Comment: IMPORT right now has data in the first two col(Frame, Time), however there is NA's in the Fx, Fy, Fz, Mx, My, Mz columns because the first sheet(4) did not have these cols. When sheet 4/5 are added into IMPORT there are NA's for Frame, Time. Sheet 4 is Frame, Time, task, limb, trial. Sheet5&6 is Fx, Fy, Fz, Mx, My, Mz, task, limb, trial. I want to also differentiate sheet 5 col names and add an L to each col name, and add a R to sheet 6 col names.

Comment: this is my read_excel_sheets function right now:         
read_excel_sheets <- function(excelDoc) {
     nameString <- excelDoc
     
     sheets <- readxl::excel_sheets(excelDoc)
     sheets <- sheets[4:6]
     x <- do.call(rbind.fill, lapply(sheets, function(X) readxl::read_excel(excelDoc, sheet = X))) %>%
       mutate(idstring = excelDoc) %>% 
       separate(col = idstring,
                into = c("task", "limb", "trial"),
                sep = "_")
     return(x) 
   }

Comment: read_excel_sheets <- function(excelDoc) {
     sheets <- readxl::excel_sheets(excelDoc)
     sheets <- sheets[4:6]
     x <- purrr::map_df(sheets, function(X) readxl::read_excel(excelDoc, sheet = X))
     return(x)
   }
   
   IMPORT <- purrr::map_df(rawfiles, FUN = read_excel_sheets) Gives me an error: "Error in as_mapper(.f, ...) : argument ".f" is missing, with no default"

Comment: Well, difficult for me to follow this since I don't have the data to test this.

Comment: messaged privately via twitter.

Answer (score 1):

For that `data.table::rbindlist` approach just set `fill=T`:

```
library(data.table)

dt_list = lapply(5:10, function(i) {
  data.table(rnorm(i))
})
dt=rbindlist(dt_list, fill=T)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bind_rows` from the `dplyr` package, part of the tidyverse:

```
x <- list(tibble(x=runif(5)),  tibble(x=runif(5)))
y <- list(tibble(x=runif(5)),  tibble(x=runif(5)))
z = list(x, y)

ans <- bind_rows(z)
ans
A tibble: 20 x 1
        x
    <dbl>
 1 0.746 
 2 0.0669
 3 0.612 
 4 0.0702
 5 0.990 
 6 0.301 
 7 0.177 
 8 0.799 
 9 0.242 
10 0.741 
11 0.651 
12 0.113 
13 0.927 
14 0.506 
15 0.477 
16 0.922 
17 0.217 
18 0.566 
19 0.539 
20 0.327
```

Use (say) `bind_rows(..., .id="Sheet")` if you need to track which element of the list each row came from originally.